# Have I correctly shown that this subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, real-numbers

I am trying to show that the set $U=\lbrace(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|x|<\frac{1}{y^2+1}\rbrace$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I tried to prove it as follows: The map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x,y):=|x|(y^2+1)$ is continuous. Then $(-1,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$  and $f^{-1}(-1,1)=U$, so the continuity of $f$ shows that $U$ is open.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that works. Or you can define$$g(x,y)=\frac1{y^2+1}-|x|,$$and then $g^{-1}\bigl((0,\infty)\bigr)=U$. So, it's the same justification: since $g$ is continuous and $(0,\infty)$ is open, $U$ is open.